# What is the meaning of "loc" and "scale" for the distributions in scipy.stats?

Tags: distributions, fitting, scipy

I need to know the meaning of the variables `loc` and `scale` of the distributions in `scipy.stats` because I need to fit some data to several probability distribution functions for doing goodness of fit tests in order to decide which one fits better.
Specifically, it is necessary to use them always?

Comment: Do you desired to fit scaled and/or shifted probability distributions to your data?

Comment: `loc` is short for "location parameter", and `scale` is naturally any scale parameters. Location parameters would include the mean in the normal distribution and the median in the Cauchy distribution. Scale parameters are like the standard deviation in the normal distribution, or either parameter of the gamma distribution.

Comment: Wasn't this exact question closed only a few days ago? If you're deleting and reposting in an attempt to get around the closure, it will likely be counterproductive.

Comment: Please do not re-post questions that were closed. Closed question means that you need to edit it because otherwise it would not be suitable for the site. Re-posting such questions would lead to them getting closed.

Comment: Yes. I understand what you're meaning. The problem is that when I tried to edit my question after being closed, the system didn't allowed me to do it. I mean, the edited question wasn't posted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Background

The SciPy distribution objects are, by default, the standardized version of a distribution. In practice, this means that some "special" location occurs at $x=0$, while something related to the scale/extent of the distribution occupies one unit. For example, the standard normal distribution has a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1.

The `loc` and `scale` parameters let you adjust the **loc**ation and **scale** of a distribution. For example, to model IQ data, you'd build `iq = scipy.stats.norm(loc=100, scale=15)` because IQs are constructed so as to have a mean of 100 and a standard deviation of 15.

Why don't we just call them `mean` and `sd`? It helps to have a more generalized concept because not every distribution has a mean (e.g., the Cauchy distribution). Moreover, it's not always the location of the peak. The standard beta distribution is only *defined* between 0 and 1. For other versions of it, `loc` sets the minimum value and `scale` sets the valid range. For distribution with a beta-like shape extending from -1 to +1, you'd use `scipy.stats.beta(a, b, loc=-1, scale=2)`.

All of these transformations take the same form:
`dist.pdf(x, loc, scale) = standard_dist.pdf((x - loc)/scale) / scale` It would be a good exercise to plot (say) the standard distribution, loc=±1, and scale=1, 2, 10 for a few different distributions. You'll get an intuitive sense for how these values affect the same sort of change.

### Fitting Data

Whether you should fix or fit the `loc` and `scale` values depends on the nature of your problem and the target distribution. For a normal/Gaussian distribution, they're the quantities of interest; indeed, they completely describe the distribution. As a result, I'd fit them.

For other distributions, loc/scale control the support of the distribution (i.e., the range of possible values). You may already know this from some fact about the data-generating process. For example, if you're modeling scores between -10-10 with a beta distribution, I would just fix them accordingly (though SciPy can also fit it for you).

Comment: How would I get known about what loc/scale for a such distribution are?

Comment: The actual adjustment is always the same, but the interpretations of the loc/shift parameters varies a bit. The help text for each distribution usually calls out an interpretation (e.g., it says that loc=mean, scale=sd for the standard normal dist); knowing if the value where x=0 has an interpretation helps too. Finally, if the support is bounded, loc/scale generally change the range over which it's defined.

Comment: Thanks, @MattKrause, for your explanation. I want to know if there is a documentation, different from the official help of Scipy, where I can read and get the details about how the calculations for the different distributions are done.

Comment: NIST's Engineering Handbook has a "Gallery of Distributions" that lists some common probability distributions and their location/scale parameters, so it might be a good starting point: https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda366.htm

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the scale and location parameters is not always obvious and/or documented (and also not always the same as in the NIST handbook mentioned in one of the comments), but it is relatively simple to generate distributions that have a specified mean and/or standard deviation (assuming the distribution has one) or a specified support (assuming it's finitely supported).

The idea is to create a 'standard' distribution object first, look up the needed properties (`mean`, `std`, or `support`) and then calculate the new location and scale parameters that give the wanted mean, variance or support.

Case 1 (setting mean and std dev):

```py
# We want a lognormal RV with mean 3 and std dev 2
import scipy.stats as stats
rv0 = stats.lognorm(s=2)
std0 = rv0.std()
rv1 = stats.lognorm(s=2,scale=2/std0)
mu1 = rv1.mean()
rv = stats.lognorm(s=2, loc=3-mu1, scale=2/std0)
print(rv.mean(), rv.std())
```

Case 2 (setting the support):

```py
# We want a beta RV with support on -2 to 4
import scipy.stats as stats
rv0 = stats.beta(a=2, b=0.4)
sc0 = rv0.support()[1]-rv0.support()[0]
rv1 = stats.beta(a=2, b=0.4, scale=6/sc0)
left1 = rv1.support()[0]
rv = stats.beta(a=2, b=0.4, loc=-2-left1, scale=6/sc0)
print(rv.support())
```

The intermediate step is necessary, since scaling may change the mean or lower bound of the support, but OTOH changing the location should never change the scale.

You can also make some general purpose functions out of that:

```py
import scipy.stats as stats
def set_mu_std(dist, mu, std):
    kwds = dist.kwds
    kwds['loc'] = 0
    kwds['scale'] = 1
    rv0 = dist.dist(**kwds)
    kwds['scale'] = std / rv0.std()
    rv1 = dist.dist(**kwds)
    kwds['loc'] = mu - rv1.mean()
    return dist.dist(**kwds)

rv = set_mu_std(stats.lognorm(s=2), mu=3, std=2)
print(rv.mean(), rv.std())
```

and

```py
import scipy.stats as stats
def set_support(dist, lower, upper):
    kwds = dist.kwds
    kwds['loc'] = 0
    kwds['scale'] = 1
    rv0 = dist.dist(**kwds)
    kwds['scale'] = (upper - lower) / (rv0.support()[1] - rv0.support()[0])
    rv1 = dist.dist(**kwds)
    kwds['loc'] = lower - rv0.support()[0]
    return dist.dist(**kwds)

rv = set_support(stats.beta(a=2, b=0.4), lower=-2, upper=4)
print(rv.support())
```

This may not answer the original question in general, but makes it in most cases superfluous, since you can set the quantities of interest to whatever you like, at least if your distribution has mean and variance or finite support.